# How to change record value in core data

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data

1. I have UITableView
2. There is a UISwitch in all cells.
3. My Core Data is filled by values.
4. One of core data attribute named switchValue with @"OFF" value.

now I need to:

1. If the user set the UISwitch to ON.
2. The action change the value of the switchValue attribute to @"ON" for that row.

my simple code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"courseCode"] description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"courseName"] description];
UISwitch *theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];

    cell.accessoryView = theSwitch;

    NSLog(@"%@",[[object valueForKey:@"switchValue"] description]);

    if ([[[object valueForKey:@"switchValue"] description]isEqualToString: @"ON"]) {

        theSwitch.on = YES;

    }else{

        theSwitch.on = NO;

    }


    [theSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return cell;

}
```

and the action is :

```
-(void) switchChanged: (UISwitch *) sender{


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

    if (sender.on) {

        How can I change the value?

    }else{

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the managed object, just set its value.

```
NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[object setValue:@"ON" forKey:@"switchValue"];
```

You'll have to save your managed object context at some point, too, if you want those changes to be saved to disk.

Comment: But I need to do this if the user change the UISwitch to on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the code generation facilities of the Core Data model manager (the graphs where you create your model).

However, you can always get the values with:

```
[object valueForKey:@"foo"]
```

and set them with

```
 [object setValue:value forKey:@"foo"];
```